# Storing 001 instead of 1 in variables in VBA

Tags: vba, catia

So this is the problem.
I have a number 000.045678
I have split it using split method and stored it in 2 variables A and B. Now the value of A is 0 and B is 45678
But the need is
A = 000 and B = 045678

How can this be done?
Thankyou for the help in advance.

Comment: Consider converting the numeric value into a string, then splitting the string at the decimal separator, then formatting each part accordingly, e.g. `Format(part1, "000")` or `Format(part2, "000000")`. Numbers don't have trailing or leading zeroes; it's strings you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when splitting a string containing 000.045678, you get the expected result

```
Dim inputString As String: inputString = "000.045678"
Dim SplitArray
SplitArray = Split(inputString, ".")
Dim A, B As String
A = SplitArray(0)
B = SplitArray(1)
Debug.Print A & "        " & B
```